# How do I stop hpboid.exe and hpbpro.exe from running MANY MANY times on my server?

Tags: hp, printing, drivers

I'm seeing many copies of those 2 programs running on the server. They seem to collect over time and each consume 5mb-10mb of RAM. It seems to be part of the printer driver for either the HP LaserJet 4100 or the HP Color LaserJet 4600.

Right now I have a batch file that kills all of the instances every morning at 3:30am.

```
taskkill /im hpboid.exe /f 
taskkill /im hpbpro.exe /f
```

It takes a few days for these to accumulate. Any suggestions on stopping this problem at the root?

-Ed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything I have seen on this points to updating drivers from HP.  It looks like they have updated their "Universal Print Driver" for your brand of printer as recently as July 1st.

Now that the obvious is aside, some advocate to just change the name of the .exe for the processes (described in this [Tech Arena Post](http://forums.techarena.in/xp-print-fax/929631.htm)).  As the person there notes, doing this will break the print test page option.  Good luck, hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Rename hpboid.exe and hpbpro.exe: problem solved.